# MongoDB not starting in Ubuntu 16.04 after turning on Authorization

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to add password to my mongodb but after changing `authorization` to `enabled` but mongodb doesn't start after that while trying with `sudo service mongod start`. I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@matteocontrini/how-to-setup-auth-in-mongodb-3-0-properly-86b60aeef7e8) to do the same. I even turned my firewall off. The result of `sudo service mongod status` is as follows:

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)    
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-10-03 16:56:31 IST; 1s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 17641 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)  Main PID: 17641 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 03 16:56:31 dev-76 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database. 
Oct 03 16:56:31 dev-76 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT 
Oct 03 16:56:31 dev-76 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state. 
Oct 03 16:56:31 dev-76 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

ANd if i try to login then i get the following:

```
sam@dev-76:/etc$ mongo -u admin -p mongoadmin admin
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
2018-10-03T17:06:09.418+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-10-03T17:06:09.418+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

**UPDATE**

My `mongod.conf` is as follows:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Can you provide your /etc/mongod.conf ? Seems that there is an invalid argument

Comment: It says the config is wrong. Must be a typo or something.

Comment: ok editing it...

Comment: You forgot to remove hash `#` before `security`

Comment: Oh. thank u very much...

Comment: you can post it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: its woking......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to uncomment the line

```
#security:
  authorization: enabled
```

After uncommenting the line it works,

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Also to use mongodb for persistence from my application i changed my uri like below,

```
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mycollection?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```